# How to set 2 fixed decimal places for number in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am using `v-model.number` to bind data properties, here is the snippet

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    entries: [{
        text: "Rate 1",
        rate: 1.7
      },
      {
        text: "Rate 2",
        rate: 2.00
      },
      {
        text: "Rate 3",
        rate: 3.50
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(entry,index) in entries">
    <h2>{{ entry.text }}</h2>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" v-model.number="entry.rate">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am stuck at setting decimal values with 2 fixed decimals e.g. 3.5 as 3.50 and 2 as 2.00

Comment: The `<input type="number">` HTML element is very limited, as you already experienced. Better to look for a Vue component that has such options. I found https://fengyuanchen.github.io/vue-number-input/ but there might be better ones for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event listener to the field updates (`input`) and format the number when initialised and when changed

It may need a bit more massaging, but that would mean a custom directive which is a bit outside my off the top of my head vue knowledge.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    entries: [
      { text: "Rate 1", rate: 1.7 },
      { text: "Rate 2", rate: 2.00 },
      { text: "Rate 3", rate: 3.50 }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    formatRate(value) {
      return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    },
    updateRate(index, event) {
      // Update when the user changes the input
      this.entries[index].rate = parseFloat(event.target.value);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(entry, index) in entries">
    <h2>{{ entry.text }}</h2>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control"
           :value="formatRate(entry.rate)"
           @input="updateRate(index, $event)">
  </div>
</div>
```